# is it possible to send handshake parameters over tcp socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i am trying to authorize incoming connections on a tcp socket, my current solution is sending `client_id` and `client_secret` as first request on socket.

web sockets accepts `query string` as hand shake params but does tcp sockets support handshake parameters to authorize incoming socket connection , before accepting that ?

**Update :**

what is usual solution to authorize users in socket communications ?

Comment: isn't handshake responsibility of a higher level layer than sockets?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no data associated with a TCP SYN.

Comment: thanks , i updated my question , could you please explain more ?